# Matrix Multiplication - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication

The first vector (M) has 96 elements and second one (L) has 24. The first is information in every 15mn and the second is information every hour.
What I want is to multiply the first four elements in M with the first element in L, to end up with only one vector with 96 elements, like so -

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this without making the code too complex?

Comment: If you just multiply you still have 4 values per hour, so what exactly do you want?

Comment: For that example numbers, what would be the first two numbers of the result? From your description I would expect a 96 element output, how is it accumulated to 24 elements?

Comment: @Daniel I'm sorry, my mistake, I meant 96 elements output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reshape the array,

```
a = [2,4,6,8];
b = 1:16;
c = repmat(a,4,1);
d = reshape(a,1,4*length(a));
e = b.*d;
```

note that in case you want a oneliner these can be combined

```
b.*reshape(repmat(a,4,1), 1, 4*length(a));
```

I cannot say whether this is faster than the other options, but it should not be a very large difference. Choose this in case you think it is more comprehensive.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for [`broadcasting`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html), so let [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) help you out -

```
reshape(bsxfun(@times,reshape(M,4,[]),L(:).'),1,[])
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the `kron` function you can easily generate the indices for `L`, it creates [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2....]

```
L(kron(1:numel(L),ones(1,4))).*M
```

In case you have trouble understanding `kron`, the same can be achieved using ceil:

```
L(ceil([1:numel(M)]/4)).*M
```